# Breathing and Leg Fatigue while running

Tags: running, long-distance-running, breathing

OK - I know this has been discussed and over-discussed here, and all over the web - but for me, I cannot seem to find any solutions.  I am hoping there are either professionals, or kindred-spirits with the same problem, who can offer some insights, advice or solutions.

The problem is that I get out of breath or leg fatigue = particularly when running (or walking) any kind of incline or stairs.  The same thing happens when I do any kind of squat-like exercise.

When I run, essentially what happens is that I can run a few paces (20?) and then either my legs just get tired, or out of breath and I have to walk 10-20 paces. On a completely flat surface I can go up to 100 paces without stopping.

Before I get a deluge of knee-jerk advice, a few facts:

1. I am in my late 40s, and in very good health and shape.
2. This problem has been with me since I can remember (in my 20s).
3. **I have had thorough medical workups - stress tests etc - from the Mayo clinic. In perfect health. (My wife and many friends are cardiologists).**
4. **I have been running for 15 years or more ...  in the past 5 years I have been running an average of 8-11 miles, 3 times a week.**
5. In the past 18 months, I have run a few 10ks and a half marathon.
6. My running times have really never improved (due to this breathing/leg fatigue issue. The running times are embarrassingly bad (for someone who runs so much).
7. every other day I work out with weights, and do some stretching.
8. I have  also tried combinations of vitamins and albuterol inhaler ... with no real effect  (I measure almost everything about my runs ... from the temperature, elevations, to caffeine intake, sleep etc)
9. Maybe, in 1 out of every 30 runs, I have a few good uninterrupted stretches of running (100-200 paces) ...
10. in the half marathon last year (flat surface) I was able to run for an uninterrupted 1200 paces in one stretch.
11. Overall this breathing/leg problem has not gotten any better or worse over the past 5+ years, except that recently I moved to an area where my runs are always on some kind of slight incline. (incidentally my running does not improve all that much on the decline!)

I am really running out of solutions and getting to the point where I don't want to run anymore.

Any insights from experienced runners? inexperienced? trainers? faith healers? I'll try anything any this point!

Thanks!

Comment: 8-11 miles per session? Or per week? And re #6, you arent running all that much. Most people would consider 30 mpw to be 5k training or barely adequate for a 10k.

Comment: This is almost bordering on medical advice. But, what is your weight? Have you been running the same amount? What is your build? Do you only do aerobic or do you do anaerobic too? Have you tried squats? Are you following progressive overload principles? Do you measure your heart rate?I consider myself fit, but my legs hurt and I get out of breath running uphill, I just push on and deal with it, its anaerobic exercise.

Comment: 8-11 miles per run ... 3 times per week   = about 30 miles per week.  I run every other day.  On alternate days I work out with weights - and then do some kind of cardio ... lately stairmaster (to help condition hills).  I weigh 168, 5'9" (muscular - so fairly solid and in shape).  I also practice various martial arts for 25+ years and taught it for 8.  The only exercise that has ever caused me problems is the "uphill" (or upstairs) kind of activity - whether running on an incline, stairs, squat thrusts etc.

Comment: Just wondering if your weight training is interfering with your running. For some people their CNS takes a while to recover from weight training. Have you ever tried running while not in the midst of weight training?

Comment: "I run every other day. On alternate days I work out with weights - and then do some kind of cardio" -- sounds like overtraining to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is either medical or expectation-based.

Are you expecting it to be as easy? You are going uphill and so are working your muscles a lot more. You are in the Anaerobic zone for incline runs which is not the pleasant experience you will get when running in the aerobic zone.

Go to a doctor and explain all of your ailments. You could ask to be taken through a fitness assessment at a clinic where they will measure your VO2 and heart rate, this may help diagnose your problem if you have one.

Alternatively, go running up hills. If you have no medical ailments then your body will adapt over time and you will get better at running up them.

Comment: re-read my original ...  I've had several complete workups from the mayo clinic and (with mixed feelings) they have found me to be in perfect health and perfect shape. part of me wishes they found something, so i could at least try to focus on solving it. The only thing is that no medical test I have seen simulates the uphill environment  (the stress test, treadmill and ridiculous step-test are nothing).  and since I have been running steadily for many years, the "adapt" thing seems tried too.

Comment: Running uphill and squatting is hard. Are you just getting tired/out of breath or is the fatigue enough to induce vomiting/fainting? If this is not medical then it might just be your body, they way you are built (assuming posture would have been picked up in other tests) Your body might struggle more in the anaerobic zone on that specific exercise. If a incline treadmill VO2 test cannot simulate your uphill run then you are stuck. Maybe consider going running with others and talk them through your run?

Comment: Sometimes the effect is such that I can get dizzy or faint (and I don't have to be running, just walking uphill). This has happened when I have to go up a flight of stairs, normal pace, but perhaps after being seated for 10-15 mins.
No medical tests have shown anything at all (even the treadmill VO2 test). I fear that you are right - that I just have to live with it.

Comment: @CJCornell - Your VO2 tests, did they include incline protocols on the treadmill? And have you had treadmill stress tests that included inclines? (By that I mean a full cardiology type TSS). There is something going on, just because you haven't found it yet, doesn't mean it isn't there to be found.

Comment: yes included inclines on the treadmill (and stress tests).  What none of the tests ever did was a "stairmaster" kind of test - which is when I can feel the effect.

Thanks for saying "There is something going on, just because you haven't found it yet, doesn't mean it isn't there to be found." - which is what I am hoping is the case. Otherwise everyone else's conclusion of "accept it", kind of sucks.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might experience leg fatigue because of incorrect posture or technique while running. Running in a straight line and at a constant speed tends to be more efficient compared with running erratically or at various speeds. Lowering your center of gravity while running could increase your balance and power, making it easier to run without becoming fatigued.

Comment: Well my posture probably isn't that bad (and I am somewhat conscious of keeping it right) ... but do you know of any evidence (or consensus) that somewhat incorrect posture - not radically incorrect - can have such a dramatic effect on breathing and fatigue?

Comment: The only way I can think of to lower my COG while running is to squat while running. And unless the OP is completely scrunched in the torso, it's not going to affect his breathing/fatigue, especially when only going uphill.